# How to create 100% stacked bar chart with ggplot2?

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have tried to create a 100% stacked bar chart in rstudio but haven't found a way that works yet (also tried with "position", but r somehow doest recognize that)

Right now my code looks like that:

```
ggplot(andmed, aes(x= eesmärk, group = Class)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(Class))) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 2) + 
  labs(x = "eesmärk/kaaslane", y = "protsent", fill="Klass") + 
  ggtitle("...")
```

(a normal bar chart graph.[a pic of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy8k0.png))
Would like it to look similar to that:(but this one was made in SAS)[how i would like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6hmV.jpg)

Comment: Usually `geom_bar(..., position="fill")`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Like MrFlick said, you can use `position = "fill"` to fill up the entire stacked barchart. Additionally, since it looks like one group (`DSC`) takes up most of the barchart, you might only want to plot `geom_text()` for a specific group, like in your example barchart. I went about this by putting `geom_text()` for all groups but only allowed one group (`carb == 4`) to be visible using `alpha`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
data(mtcars)

# calculate percentages, put into dataframe
df <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(carb = factor(carb)) %>% mutate(gear = factor(gear)) %>%
  group_by(gear, carb) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(per = label_percent()(freq))  # from the scales package

ggplot(df, aes(x = gear, fill = carb)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = per), 
            stat = "count",
            alpha = ifelse(df$carb == "4", 1, 0), # conditional transparency for geom_text
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]